# Do we want to participate in the Winter Bash 2015?

Tags: discussion

Same question as last year. Please do not mark it as a duplicate :P.

I have just got an invitation, asking if our site if we want to participate.

In a nutshell (quoting from the email):

> Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site
>   that chooses to participate. Users earn “hats” for their gravatars by
>   completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions
>   trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar can “wear”. We
>   track everyone’s progress earning hats in a leaderboard

You can find more if you [search for it.](https://www.google.com/?q=winter%20bash%20stackexchange)

Answer (score 5):

Well, same answer as last year :D

---

Personally I have never seen the point of this even though I'm aware it's simply a bit of fun. I suppose in this case though, it would be good to show our participation in StackExchange.

So yes, would be a good idea to accept it.